How to handle transactions from Service level for multiple repositories
I have project in which I need to create a transaction from the service level and use it across multiple repository classes . Some of the repos calls their sub repos from within.
There is a main Management Repo that is used to manage some communications between repos( like how a service supposed to be, but since I have dependency concerns have decided to choose this path).
Currently I create and handles the transactions from this Management Repo. But it is preventing the creation of proper test cases.
NB: I use a combination of ef core and Dapper inside the repos. Not that it may be a concern, just saying.
Edit: I use the same DB in all the repos and the connection for Dapper is extracted from the DBContext
This is what i currently tried but due to the structure I am not able to properly test controller.
And that is because when I mock the management repo I can call the subrepos. But when I don't mock it the create transactions will throw errors.
I know there are work arounds to test it with this structure.
But is there any way around like by moving the transaction handling to a dedicated repo?
And is that a good aproach?
public class ManagementRepo : IManagementRepo
{
    private readonly MyDBContext _context;
    private IDbContextTransaction _currentTransaction; // Initialized only when a transaction is created

    public ManagementRepo(MyDBContext context /* other dependencies */)
    {
        _context = context;
        // other initializations
    }

    public async Task BeginTransactionAsync()
    {
        _currentTransaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
    }

    public async Task CommitTransactionAsync()
    {
        if (_currentTransaction != null)
        {
            await _currentTransaction.CommitAsync();
            await _currentTransaction.DisposeAsync();
            _currentTransaction = null;
        }
    }

    public async Task RollBackTransactionAsync()
    {
        if (_currentTransaction != null)
        {
            await _currentTransaction.RollbackAsync();
            await _currentTransaction.DisposeAsync();
            _currentTransaction = null;
        }
    }

    public IDbTransaction GetCurrentTransaction()
    {
        return _currentTransaction?.GetDbTransaction();
    }

    public async Task<bool> SomeMethod(/* params */)
    {
        var res1 = await otherRepo.SomeMethod();
        var res2 = await otherRepo.SomeOtherMethod();
        /*
            Other logic
            ...
        */
        // return a value or handle the result
    }
}

Service Layer
public async Task<Asset> UpdateService(/* parameters */)
{
    await _ManagementRepo.BeginTransactionAsync();
    try
    {
        var res = await _ManagementRepo.SomeMethod(recordId, tableList);
        if (!res)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to update asset");
        }

        // Commit transaction
        await _ManagementRepo.CommitTransactionAsync();

        var asset = await _ManagementRepo.GetMethod(recordId);
        return asset;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Rollback in case of an error
        await _ManagementRepo.RollBackTransactionAsync();
        throw;
    }
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You shouldn't use these explicit transactions to begin with. Create code that can be saved in one SaveChanges call. That's the idea of a unit of work.

I think what you might want to do is to use TransactionScope for example in a process-pattern style at top level of your logic to contain all the single DB Transactions.
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    //do all required stuff here
    ...
    scope.Complete();//commit top layer transaction
}

note, that since you are most likely going to operate on different connection transaction will most likely get elavated to Distributed Transaction, so I suggest you get some reading of MSDTC and Distributed Transactions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771686(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
Here is documentation regarding TransactionScope - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope
